Visual proof of Stokes' theorem - how can we (for example) approximate a straight line by infinitesimally small aligned `v`'s? Non-standard analysis
This webpage (unfortunately not in English) provides a visual proof of Stokes' theorem.
After showing at the local level - using some particular yellow contour (and particular green / red / blue surfaces) described in the image below - that
$$ \iint_S \text{curl}\; {\bf G} \cdot d{\bf S} = \oint_C {\bf G} \cdot d{\bf r} $$
the author generalizes it to some macroscopic surface $S$ and contour $C$.
While I have perfectly understood that the circulation cancels out in the interior contours when dividing up a macroscopic contour into smaller contours (and that the same applies to the division of a surface), I don't understand why a macroscopic surface (say, a disk) and its corresponding contour (a circle) can be divided into these crazy shapes (the ones in colour in the image below). Specially, can a circle be divided into many smaller contours of the type of the yellow one below?
The question can be rephrased (I think) in a simpler form: can we approximate a straight line by many v-shaped infinitesimal elements? The v-shaped infinitesimal have some "height" but this "height" can be made as small as we want by multiplying the number of v's.
When I asked this problem in math.SE, I was told that it requires some non-standard analysis. But, according to the Wiki article on smooth infinitesimal analysis "lines are made out of infinitesimally small segments" (in this math theory) and "these segments can be thought of as being long enough to have a definite direction, but not long enough to be curved".
Should I draw the conclusion that it is impossible to approximate a straight line by infinitesimally small v's ? Hence, that the visual proof given in the webpage is wrong in dividing a macroscopic contour / surface by many of the yellow contour / Red Green Blue surfaces depicted below?

PS:

by v I mean two segments joined at their extremities, with an angle of, say, $30°$ between them.
I'm posting here, because checking the math validity of a Stokes' theorem visual proof can be of a certain interest to some physicists.


This really isn't a physics question though, why didn't you continue to pursue the question on mathematics stackexchange?

Sorry, but can you elaborate a bit further - I don't quite understand where you see these v-s (what you mean by that)? Are you interpreting the image as 2D? To me, this looks like a 3D picture, with 3 faces of a cube joined at one corner, and the yellow contour traces out the "open" edges where the rest of the cube is missing. The inset on the right is the same thing, from a different perspective - looking at the opening, towards the point M.

@FilipMilovanović No there are not any v-s in the Stokes' proof. I just tried to reformulate the problem in a lower dimension. By v I mean two segments joined with, say, $30°$ between them.

OK, but where do these 'v'-segments come in, and what you meant by "these crazy shapes"? Can you expand a bit on that? You specifically referred to the picture posted - this is why I was wondering if you're misinterpreting the image.

@FilipMilovanović I have edited my previous comment. By crazy I mean that they "live" in $3D$ while the disk (or associated contour circle) "lives" in $2D$.

I have edited my comment in response to your edit, but I guess it all works out now. :D Thanks for clarifying
